# how to create folder and file with datetime in wpf application

Tags: wpf, datetime

I have WPF application. where I want to create folder within folder with datetime format.
I tried below code

```
string reportPath= environment.currentDirectory+"\\Reports\\";
string datetime= Datetime.now.tostring("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:tt");
string todaysDateFolder= path.combine(reportPath,datetime);


//string todaysDateFolder = reportPath+datetime+"\\";  //This opetion also try but get error
```

code to create directory folderlike as below

```
 if (!Directory.Exist(reportPath))
  {
      Directory.createDirectory(reportpath);
      Directory.createDirectory(todaysDateFolder);
  } 
  else
    {
        Directory.createDirectory(todaysDateFolder); ///get error here that path format is not supported     
     }
```

if I use any fix name instead of date , It works. But I want date formatted folder also file.

Comment: What problem do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a date field in a folder or file name, it is customary to use this reverse format, so that they can be ordered correctly:

```
string formattedDate = Datetime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
```

If you format using the day first, then the folders will not be able to be ordered by date. This format also has no forbidden characters in it (like the colons (:) in your date format. You can find out which characters cannot be used in filenames in the [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247) page on MSDN.